# HTTP_USER_AGENT for iPhone returns Windows NT 6.1

Tags: php, user-agent

I'm using:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

In my PHP code in order to differentiate between iOS and Android devices on my website.

During my testing I've seen cases where an iPhone will return:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Instead of:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.4.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14D27 Safari/602.1
```

Is this an expected result?

Is there anything that can be done on the client side to cause that?

Is there a better (more reliable) way to check for an operating system on the client side using PHP?

Comment: why do you believe that iphone sends this string? are you sure that iphone sends any string at all? if we accept for a moment that user agent is sent by browser (not by phone itself), how will you reformulate your question? Is it possible to install multiple different browsers on iphone device? is it possible for users to use IE from their windows phone?

Comment: User Agent is easily spoofable, don't rely on it for anything granted. Always assume that the user can change his agent. Lots of dev tools allow you to modify your user_agent as well.

Comment: @Lashane I know it is send from an iPhone because I printed the results to the screen when testing it. The fact that the user agent is sent by the browser should not change the fact that the OS is still in the returned string. Yes, it is possible to install multiple browsers on an iphone device but how is that changing the fact the user agent should also return the OS?

Comment: So, you want to say, that you've opened safari (default browser for iphone), opened some page and this page displayed you "windows nt..."?

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier If the client side manipulate the data on purpose, I'm okay with it. But as I mentioned, that's not the case here. I used an iPhone myself without using any dev tools and still got this result.

Comment: @Lashane Yes. I printed the user agent to the screen using `echo` and so the string I mentioned in my question with windows NT

Comment: then it is either horrible apple bug (post it to them, they have bounty program) or you have discovered first virus for ios

Comment: actually - check this out https://www.technipages.com/ios-change-the-user-agent-in-safari

Comment: Thanks @Lashane . I highly doubt if that was done on the device I used for testing but it is worth checking.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Giving you comment from before and what Lashane just shared, is there a better way to check for the device OS, other than user-agent?